# Getting data in intent giving error in only one activity

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity

I'm trying to pass an **intent** from **adapter** and get it in my activity.

Whenever I did this it went to the **else condition**.

It **doesn't get the value** and I don't no why. When I try the same code in any **other activity** it worked perfectly, but in this activity it always gives a **null** value in intent.

I know there are so many answers to how to get and pass intent, but in my case it doesn't work in one activity and I don't know why.

> My Adapter class:

```
holder.getSurvey.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(context,AuthorMainScreen.class);
            intent.putExtra("work", "getting");
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
```

> My AuthorMainScreen  Activity:

```
  public class AuthorMainScreen extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

      Button newSurveyBtn, surveyWithRef, surveyResult;
      ArrayList<JSONObject> jsonObjects = new ArrayList<JSONObject>();

      public static TextView textView;
      DatabaseReference databaseReference, surveyReference;

      String referenceNo, loggedInUserId;
      AlertDialog dialog;
      ProgressDialog progressDialog;
      DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
      NavigationView navigationView;
      LinearLayout linearLayout;
      FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
      TextView headerEmailView, rateOk;
      Button headerLogout;
      EditText reference;


      @Override
      protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          setContentView(R.layout.activity_author_navigation);

          progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
          progressDialog.setMessage("Processing your request...");

          viewDeclaration();

          clickFunctionalities();

          ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                  this, drawerLayout, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
          drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(toggle);
          toggle.syncState();

          //drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);

          navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
      }


      private void clickFunctionalities() {
          newSurveyBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
              @Override
              public void onClick(View view) {
                  surveyTitleDialog();
              }
          });

          surveyWithRef.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
              @Override
              public void onClick(View v) {
                  referenceDialog();
                  rateOk.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                      @Override
                      public void onClick(View view) {
                          referenceNo = reference.getText().toString().trim();

                          if (!referenceNo.isEmpty()) {
                              progressDialog.show();
                              getSurvey();
                              dialog.dismiss();
                          } else {
                              progressDialog.dismiss();
                              reference.setError("Reference # is required");
                          }
                      }
                  });
              }
          });

          surveyResult.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
              @Override
              public void onClick(View view) {
                  referenceDialog();
                  rateOk.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                      @Override
                      public void onClick(View view) {
                          referenceNo = reference.getText().toString().trim();

                          if (!referenceNo.isEmpty()) {
                              progressDialog.show();
                              getSurveyResultFile();
                              dialog.dismiss();
                          } else {
                              progressDialog.dismiss();
                              reference.setError("Reference # is required");
                          }
                      }
                  });

              }
          });


          linearLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
              @Override
              public void onClick(View v) {
                  if (drawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
                      drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                  } else {
                      drawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                  }
              }
          });

          headerLogout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
              @Override
              public void onClick(View v) {
                  FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
                  Intent intent = new Intent(AuthorMainScreen.this, LoginSignupActivity.class);
                  startActivity(intent);
                  finish();
              }
          });
      }

      private void surveyTitleDialog() {

          final AlertDialog.Builder textBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

          LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
          View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.survey_name_dialog, null);

          final EditText surveyName = view.findViewById(R.id.edt_set_survey_name);
          TextView ok = view.findViewById(R.id.survey_name_btn);

          ok.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
              @Override
              public void onClick(View view) {
                  String surveyTitleName = surveyName.getText().toString().trim();
                  if (!surveyTitleName.equals("")) {
                      dialog.dismiss();
                      Intent intent = new Intent(AuthorMainScreen.this, MakeSurvey.class);
                      intent.putExtra("surveyname", surveyTitleName);
                      Toast.makeText(AuthorMainScreen.this, surveyTitleName, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                      startActivity(intent);

                  } else {
                      surveyName.setError("Title is Required");
                  }

              }
          });

          TextView cancelBtn = view.findViewById(R.id.dismiss_dialog);
          cancelBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
              @Override
              public void onClick(View view) {
                  dialog.dismiss();

              }
          });

          textBuilder.setView(view);
          dialog = textBuilder.create();
          dialog.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE);
          dialog.show();
          Window window = dialog.getWindow();
          window.setLayout(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
          dialog.setCancelable(false);
      }

      private void getSurvey() {

          surveyReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(Constants.content).child(Constants.survey).child(referenceNo);
          surveyReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
              @Override
              public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                  System.out.println(dataSnapshot);

                  if (dataSnapshot.hasChildren()) {
                      progressDialog.dismiss();
                      Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), GetSurveys.class);
                      intent.putExtra(Constants.ref_no, referenceNo);
                      startActivity(intent);
                  } else {
                      progressDialog.dismiss();

                      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Reference number is not valid !!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                  }
              }

              @Override
              public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                  progressDialog.dismiss();

                  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Something went wrong!!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
              }
          });
      }

      public void getSurveyResultFile() {
          databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(Constants.content).child(Constants.Answers).child(loggedInUserId).child(referenceNo);

          databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
              @Override
              public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                  if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                      progressDialog.dismiss();

                      JSONArray dataSnapshotArray = new JSONArray();
                      JSONArray dataSnapshotChildrenArray;
                      JSONObject dataSnapshotChildrenAnswer;
                      JSONArray dataSnapshotChildrenAnswerValues;

                      for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                          System.out.println("sdsd" + ds);
                          dataSnapshotChildrenArray = new JSONArray();
                          ArrayList<Object> list = (ArrayList<Object>) ds.getValue();
                          for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
                              HashMap<String, Object> map = (HashMap<String, Object>) list.get(i);
                              Iterator<Map.Entry<String, Object>> finalIterator = map.entrySet().iterator();

                              dataSnapshotChildrenAnswer = new JSONObject();
                              while (finalIterator.hasNext()) {
                                  Map.Entry<String, Object> entry = finalIterator.next();
                                  Object value = entry.getValue();
                                  String key = entry.getKey();
                                  try {
                                      dataSnapshotChildrenAnswer.put(key, value);
                                      if (value instanceof ArrayList) {
                                          dataSnapshotChildrenAnswerValues = new JSONArray();
                                          ArrayList<String> answers = (ArrayList<String>) value;
                                          for (int j = 0; j < answers.size(); j++) {
                                              dataSnapshotChildrenAnswerValues.put(answers.get(j));
                                          }
                                          dataSnapshotChildrenAnswer.put(key, dataSnapshotChildrenAnswerValues);
                                      }
                                  } catch (JSONException e) {
                                      e.printStackTrace();
                                  }
                              }
                              dataSnapshotChildrenArray.put(dataSnapshotChildrenAnswer);
                          }
                          dataSnapshotArray.put(dataSnapshotChildrenArray);
                          System.out.println("jso  " + dataSnapshotArray);
                      }
                      try {
                          saveCsv(dataSnapshotArray);
                      } catch (IOException e) {
                          e.printStackTrace();
                      } catch (JSONException e) {
                          e.printStackTrace();
                      }
                  } else {
                      Toast.makeText(AuthorMainScreen.this, "Sorry!!user or survey not found.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                      progressDialog.dismiss();
                  }
              }

              @Override
              public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
              }
          });

      }

      public void saveCsv(JSONArray outerArray) throws IOException, JSONException {
          if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
              if (checkSelfPermission(android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                  ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);
              }
          }

          String fileName = referenceNo + " Result";
          String rootPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/test/";
          File dir = new File(rootPath);
          if (!dir.exists()) {
              dir.mkdir();
          }
          File file = null;
          file = new File(rootPath, fileName);
          if (!file.exists()) {
              progressDialog.dismiss();
              file.createNewFile();
          }
          if (file.exists()) {
              progressDialog.dismiss();
              CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(file), ',');
              for (int i = 0; i < outerArray.length(); i++) {
                  JSONArray innerJsonArray = (JSONArray) outerArray.getJSONArray(i);
                  for (int k = 0; k < innerJsonArray.length(); k++) {
                      String[][] arrayOfArrays = new String[innerJsonArray.length()][];
                      JSONObject innerJsonObject = (JSONObject) innerJsonArray.getJSONObject(k);
                      String[] stringArray1 = new String[innerJsonObject.length()];

                      //stringArray1[0]= (String) innerJsonObject.getString("type");

                      stringArray1[1] = "Questions";
                      stringArray1[2] = "Answers";
                      stringArray1[1] = (String) innerJsonObject.getString("title");
                      stringArray1[2] = "";
                      JSONArray jsonArray = (JSONArray) innerJsonObject.getJSONArray("answer");
                      for (int j = 0; j < jsonArray.length(); j++) {
                          stringArray1[2] += jsonArray.get(j).toString();
                          stringArray1[2] += ",";
                      }

                      arrayOfArrays[k] = stringArray1;
                      writer.writeNext(arrayOfArrays[k]);
                      System.out.println("aa " + Arrays.toString(arrayOfArrays[k]));
                  }
              }

              writer.close();
              Toast.makeText(this, fileName + " is been saved at " + rootPath, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
          }
      }

      public void referenceDialog() {

          final AlertDialog.Builder rateBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

          LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
          View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.survey_refno_dialog, null);

          reference = view.findViewById(R.id.edt_survey_ref_no);
          rateOk = view.findViewById(R.id.ref_btnOk);
          TextView rateCancel = view.findViewById(R.id.ref_btnCancel);

          rateBuilder.setView(view);

          rateCancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
              @Override
              public void onClick(View view) {
                  dialog.dismiss();
              }
          });
          dialog = rateBuilder.create();
          dialog.show();
          Window rateWindow = dialog.getWindow();
          rateWindow.setLayout(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
          dialog.setCancelable(false);
      }

      private void viewDeclaration() {
          newSurveyBtn = findViewById(R.id.new_surveys_button);
          surveyWithRef = findViewById(R.id.get_survey_button);
          surveyResult = findViewById(R.id.analyze_survey);
          linearLayout = findViewById(R.id.hamburg_icon_layout);
          drawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
          navigationView = findViewById(R.id.navigation_view);
          View view = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
          headerEmailView = view.findViewById(R.id.header_email);
          headerLogout = findViewById(R.id.nav_logout);

          firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
          if (firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser() != null) {
              String userEmail = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getEmail();
              headerEmailView.setText(userEmail);
          }

          if (firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser() != null && firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid() != null) {
              loggedInUserId = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
          }
      }

      @Override
      public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {
          switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
              case R.id.menu_share:
                  Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                  intent.setType("text/plain");
                  intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "DataPro");
                  intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Constants.shareMessage);
                  startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share Via"));
                  drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                  break;
              case R.id.menu_survey_count:
                  startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), UserAllSurveys.class));
                  drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                  break;
              case R.id.menu_new_instruments:
                  startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), CreateInstrument.class));
                  drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                  break;
              case R.id.menu_about_us:
                  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "About us", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                  drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                  break;
          }
          return true;
      }

      @Override
      protected void onStart() {
          super.onStart();
          Intent intent = getIntent();
          /* if (intent.hasExtra("work") ) {
              String k = getIntent().getStringExtra("work");
              Toast.makeText(this, k, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          } else {
              Toast.makeText(this, "eroor", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          } */

          Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
          if (bundle != null ) {
              String k = bundle.getString("work");
              Toast.makeText(this, k, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          } else {
              Toast.makeText(this, "error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          }
      }

      @Override
      public void onBackPressed() {
          super.onBackPressed();
      }
```

Comment: post your error logs.

Comment: I recommend you to have a look on this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z8rd62Rv3r0 it's easy to understand.

Comment: @JohnLe Iam working in java bro and your are recommending kotlin tutorial

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have another class with the same class name, but different package name?

Because it seems like there is no extra parameter present in your receiver activity (AuthorMainScreen). Sometimes mistakes like this can take more time than any other logical mistake. Or you can try to call it onCreate() by commenting the rest of the code. Just check this.

Comment: I cant place it in oncreate because its the main class whihc appear after splash and Oncreate only called once while creating activity I have to put it in onStart onResume or in onRestart

Comment: Your adapter class belongs to which Activity?. Is it the part of the splash Screen?

Comment: It looks like there is something missing in your flow.Check getSurvey click by putting toast on it Whether it is being called or not. Also, check is there any way to go to AuthorMainScreen class other than this adapter's view click.

Comment: Its not getting intent from other activity also and I have checked the activity passing the intent with value on getSurvey Click its not passing null

Comment: Now this is weird.Try to comment code inside onCreate in AuthorMainScreen class.May be due to some other error inside the code of onCreate It is not even going to instantiate the class

Comment: I dont know but issue is not in onCreate the culprit is something else

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
if (bundle != null ) {
   String k = bundle.getString("work");
   Toast.makeText(this, k, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
} else {
   Toast.makeText(this, "error" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: Its still coming in the false statement

Comment: Iam updating my question chk it

Comment: Looks everything is ok in your code and it should work.

Comment: this activity is also not taking intent from any other activity

Comment: You can share your all other class which is related to `AuthorMainScreen` class. especially from where you call this activity like  `adapter`.